# How to get Sysdate in qweb/odoo 11?

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-11

How to reference Sysdate in qweb in odoo 11?

I need to compare a date with "sysdate" in qweb, but I'm not able to get the current date.

Comment: the solution is the method Date() e.g: <t t-esc="Date()" />

Answer (score 1):

This way you can get date and time

```
<span t-esc="context_timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"/>
```

If you want only date

```
<span t-esc="context_timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this you can get the today's date.

```
<span t-esc="context_timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')"/>
```